# What's the best way to use RSYNC with low bandwidth?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, ubuntu-server

i use rsync to make a backup of a webserver with the following options:

```
rsync -avz -H --nummeric-ids --delete --update \
      -e 'ssh -i MY_ID_RSA' \
      user@myserver.com:<PATH> <LOCAL_PATH> \
      --exclude-from=<MY_EXCLUDE_LIST>
```

First... i want to know whether it's the best way to sync with a low bandwidth?
Or is there a a way to secure transfer only the changed parts of a file and not the whole file again (like dropbox) and should be optimized for low bandwith?

another little question is how to transfer a huge image (500 GB)?
a few days ago i've transfered it and the file seems to be broken and failed to use the file :( ...maybe i've transfered it wrong?

thanks for help!

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/394049/rsync-throttle-upload-bandwidth-bwlimit-kbps

Comment: PS: is --inplace and/or --no-whole-file option(s) usefull or recommended?

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to transfer huge files using TCP or HTTP because of latency, and the errors that come from the TCP protocol.

Many companies have turned to UDP to transfer those large files.

Answer (score 0):

rsync does what you described by default - it has a delta transfer algorithm that sends only the changed parts of a file and not the whole file again. IOW `--no-whole-file` is the default. Also, read the manual page for the effects of `--inplace` on bandwidth - it doesn't sound like it would be beneficial.